# Subtract next number in sequence from the one before excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to subtract the next number in the sequence from the previous number so 2 from 1, 4 from 3 and so on. Ideally, it would find those "pairs" and then subtract the time from that row so I also need a way to do that

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there are no sequential "START" options for the same behavior; Something along these lines:

[image]

Formula in `F2`:

```
=IF(D2="START",XLOOKUP(C2,C3:C$11,B3:B$11)-B2,"")
```

Comment: You are a brilliant human thank you so much for this

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, you want to subtract the timestamps when the status equals "STOP" and the previous status equals "START". For such situation, you might use the following formula:

```
=IF(AND(D2="START",D3="STOP"),B3-B2,"")
```

This puts the time difference in that particular case and a blank cell in the other case, resulting in something like this:

```
Difference
<BLANK>
9.8
<BLANK>
21.3
<BLANK>
12.8
...
```

(Keep in mind that I've used rounded values, which are slightly different than yours)

Comment: Very close however my data is not in sequential order hence the reason for labelling each behaviour with 1,2,3,4 and so on. You will notice at the bottom other browser 1 and other browser 2 are separated by a blank case so what I really need to do is is find the next number in the sequence and either "pair" them then subtract the time or something else.

Comment: @Ivy44: In that case, the situation becomes far more complicated. I would advise you to start looking in `XLookup()` (`VLookup()` won't work because the column with the values is placed in front of the the column, containing the search item).